# What is the difference between += and =+ C assignment operators

Tags: c, assignment-operator, compound-assignment

I was wondering if there was a difference between `=+` and `+=` (and other assignment operators too). I tried and both did the same thing. So is there a difference or is there a convention? Do both work because my compilers dont check for standarts?

Edit: I made a mistake. I used bad inputs during my testing which led me to thinking they are both doing the same thing. Turns out they are two different things.

`+=` **adds** rvalue to lvalue

```
x += y;
x = x + y;
```

`=+` **assigns** rvalue to lvalue

```
x =+ y;
x = +y;
x = y;
```

Comment: There is no `=+` operator in C.

Comment: @EugeneSh. yes but it works. So should i not use it? It only works by chance in my computer?

Comment: I works as two different operators. Assignment and unary `+`.

Comment: Well `i=+1` will work indeed...

Comment: `=+` is the assignment operator along with the unary `+` operator while the `+=` is the assignment operator along with the addition operator.

Comment: https://ideone.com/1Zgtcx Notice the difference...

Comment: All compound assignment operators begin with the arithmetic operator (`+` in this case) and are then *followed* by the assignment operator (`=`). In C, `+=` is a valid compound assignment operator, whereas `=+` is not.

Comment: @EugeneSh.: strictly, there is no longer a `=+` operator in C.  It ceased to be a part of C in the mid-70s.  Note that `=+`, `=-`, `=&` can both appear in modern C — even `=*` if the term following is a pointer.  Most of the others can't.  However, the meaning is of the two separate operators; the fact that they're touching is immaterial.

Comment: If you have: `int main(void) { int i = 2, j = 3; i =+ j; printf("%d\n", i); return 0; }`, do you get 3 or 5 printed?  Standard C says it should be 3.  Even I've never worked with a compiler that gives a different result — the change from the original `=+` to `+=` occurred years before I started coding in C.

Comment: surprisingly  `=+` works .  `foo =+ bar` is same with `foo = (+ bar)`

Comment: @SunggukLim: There's nothing surprising about that. `=+` is two operators, `=` and `+`. See my answer for details.

Answer (score 20, accepted):

In modern C, or even moderately ancient C, `+=` is a compound assignment operator, and `=+` is parsed as two separate tokens. `=` and `+`. Punctuation tokens are allowed to be adjacent.

So if you write:

```
x += y;
```

it's equivalent to

```
x = x + y;
```

except that `x` is only evaluated once (which can matter if it's a more complicated expression).

If you write:

```
x =+ y;
```

then it's parsed as

```
x = + y;
```

and the `+` is a unary plus operator.

*Very* early versions of C (around the mid 1970s, before the publication of K&R1 in 1978) used different symbols for compound assignments. Where modern C uses `+=`, early C used `=+`.  Early C had no unary `+` operator, but it did have a unary `-` operator, and the use of `=-` caused problems; programmers would write `x=-y` intending it to mean `x = -y`, but it was silently interpreted as `x =- y`.  The language was changed some time between 1975 and 1978 to avoid that problem.  As late as 1999, I worked with a compiler (VAXC on VMS) that would warn about an ambiguous use of `=-`, but would use the older meaning. That shouldn't be a concern now unless you're a hobbyist playing with some *very* old software and/or hardware.

(A 1975 [C Reference Manual](https://www.bell-labs.com/usr/dmr/www/cman.pdf) shows the old `=-`, `=+`, et al forms of the compound assignment operators. The first edition of **The C Programming Language** by Kernighan and Ritchie, published in 1978, shows the modern `-=`, `+=`, et al, but mentions the older forms under "Anachronisms".)

Comment: To this day I still put a space after the `=` so `a = -7;` is not misinterpreted as `a -= 7;`.

Comment: @chux-ReinstateMonica So do I, but only because I find it more legible.